# Positioning a block in product detail, magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, position

I've been looking for positioning a block (it's a banner image). In the product details section, my layout is set in '3columns', I want to insert it in top of the three columns, inside of the container div (its class is "columns")

I've created a static block, then a widget to positioning; and the positions available aren't the one i'm looking for.

If you want to know, I would like to change the structure of the 3 columns + my block

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can select "Before Main Columns" container and render your CMS block **before** div.columns if you are using widget to add it to the product details page.

[image]

Containers are defined in **[Magento/Theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml)**:

```
<container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>
<container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
```

The missing label of columns container excludes it from the dropdown with containers in the admin area. This is some kind of magento core team restrictions I think to place CMS blocks in any containers (there is a lot of structural blocks).

Anyway if you want to place that CMS block **inside the .columns div** you can create layout xml file in your theme and add the block:

Path: app/design/frontend/**Vendor**/**theme**/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="banner" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">banner</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: thanks a lot!, I will try creating a layout, it seems what I was looking for

Comment: If you have theme then this should work on 100%. Please try it and then vote if it works. :)